# Скрипт применяется только к одному идентификатору

Tags: javascript

Есть скрипт:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var element = $('#divv');

  function math_height() {
    element.height(element.width());
  }
  math_height();
  $(window).on('resize', function() {
    math_height();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="divv">a</div>
<div id="divv">b</div>
<div id="divv">c</div>
<div id="divv">d</div>
```

Скрипт работает только с первым 'div' на странице. Т.е. на странице отобразится правильно только первый блок.

Как сделать так что бы скрипт отработал со всеми **одинаковыми** идентификаторами?

Comment: Идентификаторы должны быть уникальными, используйте классы.

Comment: Сергей, я подправил код в вопросе, чтобы получился активный пример. Проверьте, правильно ли я вас понял? Кстати, по $ предположил, что у вас jQuery – верно?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это потому что ID должен быть уникальным, их нельзя несколько одинаковых. Используйте классы вместо ID.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var element = $('.divv');

  function math_height() {
    element.height(element.width());
  }
  math_height();
  $(window).on('resize', function() {
    math_height();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="border:1px solid;" class="divv">a</div>
<div style="border:1px solid;" class="divv">b</div>
<div style="border:1px solid;" class="divv">c</div>
<div style="border:1px solid;" class="divv">d</div>
```

Comment: Если вы возьмете сниппет из вопроса и сделаете на нём работающий пример решения, будет очень здорово. )

Comment: @NickVolynkin, вставил. Просто не думал, что изменение id на class может потребовать примера кода :)

Comment: P.S. - Добавил бордеры, что бы был лучше виден ресайз элементов.

Comment: Наглядный пример очень полезен в обучении. Это вам с позиции вашего опыта кажется, что всё очевидно, а новичку — не обязательно. (это когнитивное искажение называется «проклятием знания») =)

Answer (score 4):

Вы можете использовать классы вместо идентификаторов.

Если по непонятным причинам вам нужно использовать именно id, то можно использовать `document.querySelectorAll`.

[Пример на JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/42qw0bgt/)

С вашим кодом:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function math_height(element) {
    element.height(element.width());
  }

  for (const vanillaElement of document.querySelectorAll('#divv')) {
    const element = $(vanillaElement);
    math_height(element);
    $(window).on('resize', function() {
      math_height(element);
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="divv">a</div>
<div id="divv">b</div>
<div id="divv">c</div>
<div id="divv">d</div>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за советы, вариант с классами подошел)))